# What are the best Pokemon in Pokemon GO for the Master League with Mega Evolutions?

Tags: pokemon-go

**Based on the current meta (May 2022)** and consider the actual rules for the Master League with Megas, so I would like to know what is the best ranking to create my team.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This looks like an opinion-based questions and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: There are also guides on this topic easily findable online wth Google - try Reddit, GamePress and Dextro

Answer (score 3):

Based on a ranking of positive match-ups against the core meta and the entire format, the Mega Pokemon with the best match-ups is Mega Gyarados (about 85% against the core meta and 95% against the entire format). This is followed by Mega Latios, who has a lower win rate against the core meta (79%) but a higher win rate against the entire format (96%). Source is [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphArena/comments/uz1gzt/budget_busters_mega_master_league_meta_analysis/) which used PvPoke simulations.

If you want a ranking of every Pokemon in Master League with Megas, [PvPoke has provided a list](https://pvpoke.com/rankings/mega/10000/overall/). There are assumptions with this ranking which should be taken into consideration, most notably both Pokemon have 1 shield each and shields are always used at the first available opportunity.